# lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, macros

**example which work:**

```
#define DIR(n,d) (d==LEFT?n.left:n.right)

struct node {
struct node*left;   
struct node*right;
int value;  
};

struct node n;
n.left=malloc( sizeof(struct node) );   
n.right=malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  

DIR(n,d)->value=26;

(d==1?n.left:n.right)->value=26;
```

**example which (doesn't work):**

```
#define DIR(mem,d) d==LEFT?mem->left:mem->right
```

or

```
#define DIR(mem,d) (d==LEFT?(*mem).left:(*mem).right)
```

Another structure:

```
 struct Node{
    char color;
    int height;
    Node* parent;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Container*data;
 };
```

In main function i do the following:

```
Node*temp;
Node*mem=malloc( sizeof(Node) );
d=LEFT;
temp=malloc( sizeof(Node) );
DIR(mem,d) = temp;
```

Error:  ***lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    DIR(mem,d) = temp;***

Thank you.

Comment: The error message states that clear. The value of the LHS is not an lvalue. That happens when you get too fancy with macros. Solution: don't use such macros. They are not worth the hassle you get when debugging and don't spare typing. What's wrong with `mem->left`? (FYI: `p->m` is **identical** to `(*p).m`. Don't use the latter (more typing, less clear).

Comment: So what will be the answer? What should i do? how i could access struct element in second case?

Comment: To improve your question, remove all the stuff that "works".  You only need to post what doesn't work.  There is about 4 lines of relevant info and a bunch of junk. Don't include the `-E` output either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator does not yield an lvalue in C. One alternative is:

```
#define DIR(n,d) *((d)==LEFT?&(n).left:&(n).right)
```

Note that you should parenthesize all uses of macro parameters.

Comment: i actually tried this and it doesn't work either, now i'm trying to access something in not a structure or union

Comment: @M.M, you need to dereference the passed pointer: `#define DIR(n,d) *((d)==2?&((*n).left):&((*n).right))`

Comment: @Anatoly use `*mem` as the parameter or follow Alter Mann's suggestion. In future it would be good to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as that makes it easier for people to post exact answers

Comment: @AlterMann OK, in the original question it wasn't clear whether the argument was a pointer or not

Comment: I didn't change anything in question except of what you told me to remove